# add Datetime values inside IN query clause in a different context

Tags: apex, datetime, date, dynamic-binding

I am trying to create a query dynamically which contains the `Date` and `Datetime` values with `IN` clause with `WHERE`

For example,

```
SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Program__c IN ('Online','On Campus') AND Expected_Start_Date__c IN :expectedStartDateList
```

The issue is I can not use `expectedStartDateList` with `IN` clause as it lies in a different context. The Value of `expectedStartDateList` is generated dynamically and it can contain any number of Date/Datetime values.

is there a way to add `Date` and `Datetime` value with `IN` without using `:expectedStartDateList`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are always better off using binding variables since these are proof against SOQL injection attacks and you don't have to worry about how to format up values into your query.

However, where you have to inject values (because you cannot use bindings for some reason) then dates and date times must be specially formatted.

Datetime values can be appropriately inserted into your SOQL query using something like:

```
'MyDateTimeField__c >= ' + myDatetime.formatGmt('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'HH:mm:ss\'Z\'')
```

Dates need to be in the form yyyy-MM-dd.

You use these formats along with the required IN markup:

```
// A string containing formatted date/datetime values with commas between
String commaSeparatedFormattedDateTimeValues = ...;

String queryPart = 'MyDateTimeField__c IN (' + commaSeparatedFormattedDateTimeValues + ')'
```